# In fancytooltips, how to set size of background color box

Tags: fancytooltips

I want the size of background colore box to automatically match the "size" of formula to be displayed. What I get is a box spanning size of page. as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!50}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\keytip{M2} \begin{shaded}
\[
M= \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \beta   \\
\gamma & \delta  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to box the equation, calculate its width and use this width for a `minipage` containing the expression; here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!50}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

% fill the box
\savebox\mybox{%
  \Huge$\displaystyle M= \begin{bmatrix}
  \alpha & \beta   \\
  \gamma & \delta  \\
  \end{bmatrix}$%
}

\keytip{M2}
% use the width of the box as the minipage width
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\wd\mybox}
\begin{shaded}
\usebox\mybox
\end{shaded}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: do not use diplayed equation, use inline math and the `\colorbox` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!50}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\keytip{M2} \colorbox{shadecolor}{
  $\displaystyle
  M= \begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha & \beta   \\
    \gamma & \delta  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that for optimal result you should either use `\pagestyle{empty}` and `pdfcrop` to remove the margins or set the dimensions of the page to the dimensions of the yellow box.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of interactively moving the tip around by dragging it?

Comment: Not now. To get such a behavior I can suggest the technique used in this paper: http://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Bulletin/V72P1/pdf/721-5019-LoPo.pdf - click the reference to some of the figures. Then hover mouse to the popup to see the instructions. Note that you are allowed to have more popup widgets on one PDF page, which is impossible in current fancytooltips.

Comment: I noticed that, there, the popup is used even if a figure is on the same page as the reference and, on page [9]/25,  it causes half of tip to be cut off by the top of the page. What package is used on that paper?

Comment: I think that the package is not available on CTAN (Juny 2012).